# Automatically detecting UIButton clicks throughout a View Controller for designing an Analytics SDK - iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

In our app, we need to detect each and every user click on all the UIButtons inside each and every ViewController. Our project is massive, with many `UIViewController`s, each having many `UIButtons` inside. I have added a `analyticsEvent` String to the `UIButton` class inside an extension using Objc's AssociatedObjects, and the desired behavior is to send that string to the server once the button is clicked. I would like to know how would you go about handling this.

1- Adding a click-target for each and every button manually. I don't like this, takes ages. And it makes the code base smell like a swamp.

2- Make a custom UIBUtton instance, do something in it and have all the UIButtons in the app use that. I don't like this, as there are many buttons and it'd need massive refactoring.

3- Override some base function using extensions to understand when a UIButton is tapped. For example, I tried this:

```
extension UIButton {

    open override func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
        let result = super.point(inside: point, with: event)
        if result {
            print("SangriaButtonBounds", "Send event to the server")
        }
        return result
    }

}
```

This is dangerous, and sometimes gets fired multiple times, which is expected as its usage is for sth else.

4- Another thing is to maybe add a click-target whenever the button is initialized using extensions, but some parts of the codebase are sometimes deleted all the targets on an Object and adding them, and it'd need special handling in such case.

I guess there is some function out there which I can add some behavior to it using the extensions to it, but not sure what it is.

I would like to know what would be the best approach to this in your opinion.

Comment: I would either override or swizzle `sendAction:to:forEvent:` of `UIControl`

Answer (score 0):

I hate to tell you this, but the correct answer is to override and create a custom UIButton subclass where you can put custom logic in.

What you're doing is attempting to add custom functionality to all objects of a certain type, this is exactly what OOP is designed to be great at.

It's a big job to be sure, but doing anything else like overriding something lower-level like UIControl could lead to extremely hard-to-find bugs every time someone tries to touch, for instance, a UISwitch and gets a side effect.

Comment: Creating a UIButton subclass (Presentation) to handle analytics (Side effect) is also a bad solution IMO. Analytics is a concern that doesn't belong to Presentation layer. In order to make this properly isolated from Presentation you need to have an architecture that supports it. UI events like button taps should flow from Presentation layer to some kind of Domain layer where you run your logic and that's the place where you should track them.